# Is it possible to use persisted face ids in Identify process

Tags: face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

In order to use the "Identify", I first need to detect faces in an image using "Face Detect", then I have to pass those to faceIds (at most 10 at a time) to be used in identification. Those faces expire after 24 hours.

FaceIDs stored in LargeFaceList (or FaceList) are not expired and can be used until they are deleted. So can I use FaceIDs stored in a LargeFaceList in "Identify" calls? Or do I have to keep using Face Detect to use "Identify"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask what's your scenario to use the faceId for "Identify" after 24 hours? 
And second, to answer your question, the current API does not support using "persistedFaceId" as input to "Identify" call, if the time frame past 24 hours, you have to do "Detect" again to get the "faceId" to feed to "Identify". If you can provide your scenario, this would help the Service provider to understand the need.

Comment: Well, that answers my question. As the scenario though. We are detecting and identifying faces in a longer period then 24 hours. So when we add a new user to the person group, then train it, if 24 hours is passed, we need to detect all the faces from the previous images, get face ids and then identify them again. It's ok in case of 1-3k images but it becomes problematic when we have 10k+ images. Face API also adds time based request limitations, therefore we cannot parallelize those requests a lot as well.